# CoreTelephony`(anonymous namespace)::GetRadioModuleProperty Error in XCode when attempting to run App on a Test Device

Tags: xcode, exc-bad-access, core-telephony

I'm relatively new to iPhone development and XCode in general and have no idea how to begin troubleshooting an CoreTelephony issue . I come from a Java background so memory management and pointers are a tad rusty for me, and to further complicate things, the last time I looked at an iPhone project Objective-C required you to release objects when unloading, which appears to have changed?

I am attempting to use the library: CoreTelephony.h, CoreTelephony.m in a proof of concept app to get the imei number for the phone.

Code snippet:

// Code to request the web app url for the web view
    [appView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fullURL]]];

```
// Code to call apple's private core telephony framework
NSString *imei;
_CTServerConnectionCopyMobileIdentity(result, sc, &imei);
```

The code is throwing a Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=13, address=0x0) error at :
_CTServerConnectionCopyMobileIdentity(result, sc, &imei);

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

CoreTelephony.h code:

```
//
struct CTServerConnection
{
    int a;
    int b;
    CFMachPortRef myport;
    int c;
    int d;
    int e;
    int f;
    int g;
    int h;
    int i;  
};
struct CTResult
{
    int flag;
    int a;
};

struct CTServerConnection * _CTServerConnectionCreate(CFAllocatorRef, void *, int *);


void _CTServerConnectionCopyMobileIdentity(struct CTResult *, struct CTServerConnection *, NSString **);
```

Stack dump:

```
OS Version:      iOS 6.0 (10A403)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   CoreTelephony                   0x35c4ff46 0x35c14000 + 245574
1   CoreTelephony                   0x35c5012a 0x35c14000 + 246058
2   AttendanceMonitor               0x00026c9e 0x24000 + 11422
3   UIKit                           0x36282590 0x36260000 + 140688
4   UIKit                           0x362c2d74 0x36260000 + 404852
5   UIKit                           0x362beae8 0x36260000 + 387816
6   UIKit                           0x363001cc 0x36260000 + 655820
7   AttendanceMonitor               0x000265e0 0x24000 + 9696
8   UIKit                           0x362c3ad4 0x36260000 + 408276
9   UIKit                           0x362c365e 0x36260000 + 407134
10  UIKit                           0x362bb846 0x36260000 + 374854
11  UIKit                           0x36263c3c 0x36260000 + 15420
12  UIKit                           0x362636d0 0x36260000 + 14032
13  UIKit                           0x3626311e 0x36260000 + 12574
14  GraphicsServices                0x343db5a0 0x343d5000 + 26016
15  GraphicsServices                0x343db1ce 0x343d5000 + 25038
16  CoreFoundation                  0x33700170 0x33669000 + 618864
17  CoreFoundation                  0x33700112 0x33669000 + 618770
18  CoreFoundation                  0x336fef94 0x33669000 + 614292
19  CoreFoundation                  0x33671eb8 0x33669000 + 36536
20  CoreFoundation                  0x33671d44 0x33669000 + 36164
21  UIKit                           0x362ba480 0x36260000 + 369792
22  UIKit                           0x362b72fc 0x36260000 + 357116
23  AttendanceMonitor               0x00025ba4 0x24000 + 7076
24  libdyld.dylib                   0x382f6b1c 0x382f5000 + 6940

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x323fad98 0x323e9000 + 73112
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x377accf6 0x377a6000 + 27894
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x377aca12 0x377a6000 + 27154
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x377ac8a0 0x377a6000 + 26784

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x323ea648 0x323e9000 + 5704
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x37b134ec 0x37b02000 + 70892
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x37b05df4 0x37b02000 + 15860
```

Comment: That's a very helpful link - THANK YOU, however, how am I supposed to add a stack trace, core dump etc when I don't have enough points to add screen shots to my post???????

Comment: that's all textual data, no need for images.

Comment: Have you added Coretelephony.framework?

Comment: Hi, yes I had used Core Telephony, but I was unable to figure out the issue, so I refactored the code and solution to avoid using core telephony, however for the sake of other users, it would be helpful if solutions were suggested for others who come across similar issues